# I am looking for multi-sensor fusion (camera, LIDAR) based multi-robot cooperative slam open source code or information

Tags: sensor-fusion, slam-algorithm

I am looking for open source code or information on cooperative multi-robot slam based on multi-sensor fusion. I have searched for a long time but only found an open source code based on monocular camera - ccm_slam. which doesn't fit my needs and I don't know how to change the monocular camera in the code to a depth camera (d455) fused with lidar.
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. thanks in advance.

I only found one open source code based on monocular camera on github - ccm_slam

Comment: https://seungryong.github.io/publication/depth_ICRA2018.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in my graduation design, and i borrowed a sweeping robot and learned from its lidar/imu mapping algorithm. Maybe you can have a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).